# Can we use <h:selectManyCheckBox> inside <rich:select>

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have just started to use jsf rich faces and my client wants a drop down list with multiple items with checkboxes. .
My code look like this but i am not getting desired result:

```
    <rich:select id="primaryFilterPayer1" value=""
                 styleClass="cpd-combo cpd-master-filter-width"
                 enableManualInput="true" defaultLabel="Select Payer" listWidth="300px"
                 maxListHeight="400px">
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="multipleselect"
                       title="Select one or more payer" layout="pageDirection">
<f:selectItems value="#{payerwiseDuplicate.allPayer}" var="item"
                           itemValue="#{item.key}"
                           itemLabel="#{item.value}"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
</rich:select>
```

Comment: Your question is not Java related. It cannot be demonstrated in a Java main method, nor can it be answered by Java experts.

Comment: Both of those components do similar things, I don't know how you imagine they would work combined. But importantly the reason we have dropdowns is so that we don't have to use checkboxes, there's no need to have both.

Comment: Hi @Makhiel 
I am using checkboxes  in the dropdown only because so that i can select multiple items at once, 
while in the dropdowns we can only select a item at once. 
please help.

Comment: Yes, `rich:select` can only select one thing. If you want to select multiple things there's `h:selectManyMenu` or `h:selectManyListBox` but if you want that with a dropdown you might have to look for another library.